# Unable to load the templates AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load templates in angular but get an error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND angular.js:102 Error:
>   [$compile:tpload]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/tpload?p0=pages%2Fhome.html
>       at Error (native)
>       at file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:6:417
>       at file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:137:25
>       at file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:112:113
>       at n.$eval (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:126:15)
>       at n.$digest (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:123:106)
>       at n.$apply (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:126:293)
>       at l (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:81:240)
>       at M (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:85:342)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.e (file:///C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/Video1/Starter/angular.js:86:418)

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="weatherApp">
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Weather Forecast SPA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style>
            html, body, input, select, textarea
            {
                font-size: 1.05em !important;
            }
        </style>

        <!-- load angular via CDN -->
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">AngularJS Weather</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-view></div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>

// MODULE
var weatherApp = angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

// ROUTES
weatherApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.htm',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

    .when('/forecast', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/forecast.htm',
        controller: 'forecastController'
    })

});

// CONTROLLERS
weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

I tried to use WAMP server to load the pages from, but still get the same error.

Comment: Make sure you load your javascript at the end of your body tag.  Are you referencing your modules in app.js?

Comment: I think its mostly because you are viewing the index.html from a file. Try serving your project through a server

Comment: Which browser are you using? Not all browsers are friendly with file:// paths

Comment: I think that's the problem, I loaded from WAMP server in windows, but still get the erros

Answer (score 0):

Currently your template protocol contains `file://` which would not accessible through your browser.

You need to host your code on some server(like IIS, WAMP, etc.) & paste your whole code directory on the server, in order to work your code. Other wise your code looks fine.

So the URL should be either `http://` or `https://` then your template will fetch from server directly.

Comment: I just did a few minutes ago. Thanks

Comment: @Abdi what url you putted in browser..I think you are accessing using filepath like `C:/Users/Abu-Mustaqiima/Documents/AngularJS/WeatherApp/index.html` ,I think it should be something like `http://localhost/yourpath`

Comment: I am using WAMP but not sure which file path to use, do I need to place the files at the root of the wamp folder?

Comment: yes you need to paste your whole project to wamp server root

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75861/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-abdi).

Answer (score 0):

Use https or http in URL .Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```